# Regex Match String starting with @

Tags: regex

How do I match the `@` symbol of string like `@RandomName`

---

**Some constraints:**

1. The match should begin with `@`
2. The match should be within 2 - 49 characters long.
3. The first character after `@` must be one of `A-Z, a-z, _`
4. The characters allowed in the match are `0-9, A-Z, a-z, _`
5. The match should terminate after the word ends.

---

**Some Example Strings to be matched**

1. `@RandomName`
2. `@_1RandomName`
3. `@___`
4. `@_1_`

---

This is what I have so far. It works but i'm not sure if it's the best way to do this.

`(^|\s)@(?=[^\d&%$-]\S{2,49})\b`

Comment: Can't you just use `@` to match @? "@" is not a special character in most regex engines I know.

Comment: But, I have asked for more constraints.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add it. Check now.

Comment: Your regex doesn't seem to match the requirements at all. Are there some requirements that you haven't mentioned? For example, what is the `\S{2,49}` doing there? You never mention anything about 49 characters maximum.

Comment: Not looking at your provided pattern, your requirements sound as simple as [`/^@[a-z_]\w*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/UBZ2ce/1/) and after your edit: [`^@[a-z_]\w{0,47}$`](https://regex101.com/r/UBZ2ce/3)

Comment: @sweeper added the constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first 2 char don't count in total upto 49 char:

```
(?<=^|\s)@(?=[^\W\d]\w{2,49}\b)
```

else:

```
(?<=^|\s)@(?=[^\W\d]\w{0,47}\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yp98XQ/2)

Comment: Hey, Can you make it match only the @ symbol and not the whole string. Thanks.